# Spring Rest Client want to see error message instead of exception

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

I have a spring rest client. when authentication details are not provided in the headers and I hit the service with

```
ResponseEntity<String> resp = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
```

I get exception :

> invoking error handler Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401
>   Unauthorized  at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)

But when I hit the url on mozilla browser, I get message like

```
{"errors":[{"code":"xxxx","reason":"xxxx"}]}
```

Now here is what i want: **i want to capture this error message in my code instead of getting 401 exception**. I tried to see if there is anything in the response. But the response received is null. How can I capture the error message received from the webservice ?

Comment: This is still a problem.  I want to get the response then decide for myself how to handle it, instead of having an exception thrown.  In terms of processing that is far less efficient.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I feel odd to post answer for my own question. But i finally achieved it through the following...

```
} catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getStatusCode());
      System.out.println(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
```

I was incorrectly searching for errors in response entity. But it is available in the exception.

Comment: For somebody who is looking only for the reason/message of exception: `e.getResponseBodyAsString()` returns many other things, like statusCode, statusText, etc, apart from the reason/message of the Exception. You will have to manually parse it from the exception.